# unable to set local admin password using GP

Tags: windows-7, script, batch, passwords, windows-server-2008

I'm updating our local admin script which does not include server 2008 r2.

Because 2008 and Windows 7 have same version Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] so I can't do a version search.

I have tried these option

```
systeminfo |findstr /B /C:"OS Name"|find "2008"
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto W2008
```

OR

```
wmic OS get Caption|find "2008"
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto W2008
```

But both option failes. the script is run from GP and it gets applied to computer

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: Set full path to logfile:
set logfile=C:\temp\pwd.log
:: Initialise logfile:
date /T >%logfile%
echo Starting pwd.log on %computername% >>%logfile%
:: ##############################################################
:: Set the required passwords here:
set ntw2kadmin=ntwpass
set xpvistaadmin=xppass
set w2k3admin=2003pass
set w2k8admin=P2008pass
:: ##############################################################
:: Exceptions:
if /I "%COMPUTERNAME%"=="PC1" goto SKIP
if /I "%COMPUTERNAME%"=="PC2" goto SKIP
if /I "%COMPUTERNAME%"=="PC3" goto SKIP
:: Set password based on OS version: 
ver|find "4.0" >nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto NTW2K
ver|find "5.0" >nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto NTW2K
ver|find "5.1" >nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto XPVISTA
ver|find "5.2" >nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto 2K3
ver|find "6.0" >nul|
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto XPVISTA
wmic OS get Caption|find "2008"
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto W2008

:: Catch any unusual circumstances:
goto XPVISTA
:NTW2K
echo Setting local administrator password for this NT4 or Windows 2000 machine >>%logfile%
net user Administrator %ntw2kadmin% 2>&1 >>%logfile%
goto EOF
:XPVISTA
echo Setting local administrator password for this XP or Vista or Win 7 machine >>%logfile%
net user Administrator %xpvistaadmin% 2>&1 >>%logfile%
goto EOF
:2K3
echo Setting local administrator password for this Windows 2003 Server >>%logfile%
net user Administrator %w2k3admin% 2>&1 >>%logfile%
goto EOF
:W2008
echo Setting local administrator password for this Windows 2008 r2 Server >>%logfile%
net user Administrator %w2k8admin% 2>&1 >>%logfile%
goto EOF
:SKIP
echo Not setting local administrator password for %COMPUTERNAME% >>%logfile%
goto EOF
:EOF
echo setlapwd.bat: exiting >>%logfile%
:: Remove user permissions from the logfile's ACL:
cacls %logfile% /E /R BUILTIN\Users
:: End our local scope:
endlocal
```

UPDATE:
Script gets applied to Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows Server 2003 but not to Windows 2008 r2

Comment: Why aren't you using WMI filters in group policy instead of in the script?

Comment: this is how company does so i did say we can use gp to do this but i was told to fix this. i try to update the script but 7 and 2008 use same version

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
wmic OS get Caption|find "2008"
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto W2008
```

My guess would be the error lies elsewhere in this script. A little more troubleshooting may be in order.

The whole script seems like a mess though. I'd push for a PowerShell script as a replacement, and to maybe use proper WMI filters. Or better yet, enable the following GPO:

```
Computer Configuration, Windows Settings, Security Options, Account: Administrator account status, Disabled
```

Local admin profiles aren't really a good idea in the first place.

Comment: wmic OS get Caption|find "2008"
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto W2008
when i run this on my pc it works fine but becuase gp is getting applied to PC, when pc starts up it just ignores the wmic. if I remove this this works fine for windows 7 and 2008 but the problem is that win7 and win2008 has same version number

Comment: we can't have powershell script. we have system which are running win 2000 and even 95

Comment: @James Holy %*@! Windows 95? In that case I suggest you seek new employment. Seriously. What good is experience in antiquated systems and methods?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. I have used the DSquery to search our ad, if its in server ou then process as server else process as desktop.

```
@echo off
:: Limit scope:
setlocal
:: Set full path to logfile:
set logfile=C:\tmp\passlog.log
:: Initialise logfile:
date /T >%logfile%
echo Starting passlog.bat on %computername% >>%logfile%
:: ##############################################################
:: Set the required passwords here:
::windows 2003 password
set w2k3admin=pass1
::windows 2008 password
set w2k8admin=Pass1
::windows xp, vista, 7 and 8 password
set desktopadmin=pcpass
:: ##############################################################
:: We need a copy of dsquery.exe on the local machine:
echo check dsquery file... >>%logfile%
if not exist %windir%\system32\dsquery.exe copy "\\shared\location\scripts\dsquery.exe" %windir%\system32\dsquery.exe
echo dsquery filed checked... >>%logfile%
:: Are we ignoreOU?
call dsquery computer -name %computername% | findstr /i "OU=ignoreOU"
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto ignoreOU
:: Are we a server?
call dsquery computer -name %computername% | findstr /i "OU=Servers"
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto server
:: Are we a DC?
call dsquery computer -name %computername% | findstr /i /C:"OU=Domain Controllers"
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 set goto server
::
goto desktop
:server
    ver|find "6.1" >nul
        if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto 2k8
    ver|find "5.2" >nul
        if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto 2k3
:2k8
    echo Setting local administrator password for windows server 2008... >>%logfile%
    net user Administrator %w2k8admin% 2>&1 >>%logfile%
    goto EOF
:2k3
    echo Setting local administrator password for windows server 2003... >>%logfile%
    net user Administrator %w2k3admin% 2>&1 >>%logfile%
    goto eof
:desktop
    echo Setting local administrator password for desktop/laptop... >>%logfile%
    net user Administrator %desktopadmin% 2>&1 >>%logfile%
    goto eof
:ignoreOU
    echo Not setting local administrator password for this ignoreOU server... >>%logfile%
    goto eof
:eof
echo passlog.bat: exiting >>%logfile%
:: Remove user permissions from the logfile's ACL:
cacls %logfile% /E /R BUILTIN\Users
:: End our local scope:
endlocal
```